# Constant Voltage / Constant Current / Current Foldback Regulator Evaluation

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

I am a semi-retired EE in electrical distribution, so op-amps are not in my tool bag, and I could use some help. It has been over 30years since I last worked with them, and I need help from someone willing to take a little time to look my circuit over.

The circuit below is an LDO Constant Voltage, Constant Current with Current Fold Back for a 14-volt DC, 30- Amp Power Supply and, Float Battery Charger. I took bits and pieces of circuits I had seen and incorporated them into my design with tweaks. It regulates the negative rail.

U1 (ADA 4091) and U3 (-5-volt reference)  make up the voltage regulator with feedback provided by R12 and R13 for a constant 14-volt output. M1 is a dummy MOSFET I use for the output pass element. The working circuit will use an IRF520 to drive 4 x 2N5886 in parallel configured as a common emitter pass element—first-time LTSpice user who does not know how to import parts. I told you I needed help, lol.

U2, R1 through R6, and C2 make up the current limiter.R2 and R5 in series form the voltage divider to bias the neg input to roughly -300mv. With 30-amp flowing through R1, it will turn on U2 and take control of the loop, placing the regulator in Constant Current mode. In the event of a short circuit or overload, R2 and R4 form a series voltage divider using U3 reference voltage to make the 5-amp fold back current limiter (.05 volt bias). C2 is to prevent inductive loads like a light bulb from falsely tripping the current regulator.

It works, I think, on LTSpice using the Transient command you see. I do not know how to set up a load (R14)  to step it in or turn it on/off to see how it regulates. I am not even sure I have selected the right op-amps for the job. What concerns me is stability, and I could please use some design help and critique.

THX

Dereck

[image]

Comment: For adjusting the load, you can DC sweep a current source instead of R14. But if you want to see transient responses, you may need to stay with .TRAN and use a pulsed current source where you can specify the ramp rates and landings to see it respond and settle.

Comment: I'm glad you recognize not to use a low RdsOn power FET in a linear load design.

Comment: U2 CMRR is poor and CM noise from V1 is unknown and excess gain from U2  can cause step load errors with high reactive load (1000uF)

Comment: Thanks, Tony. I am perplexed by your answer. I chose the ADA4097 because it has a high CMRR of 135 dB. Could you expand on your answer or recommend a better opamp for the application?

THX

Dereck

Comment: THE CMMR is limited by the mismatched external impedances. Intuitively if V1 has noise , it is amplified thru R6 while R3 sees a LPF in front of it.  A true INA is balanced while an Op Amp is always limited by the eternal imbalanced transfer functions on each side.